# How does a lower elevation volume affect the temperature of the volume above it?

Tags: thermodynamics

Assume you have a reasonably well thermally insulated box of air which you want to keep warm. It has at least one heat source, and it has at least one heat sink. One of the options available to you is to attach a second volume to the first, on the bottom of it, hoping to rely on the idea that the coldest air will collect in the lower volume that you do not care about.

Example:

```
+---------------+
|Volume 1       |  <-- at least one each of heat sink/source in here
|        S      |
+------------+  |
         ^   |  |
heat     |   |V2|  <-- Volume 2 added hoping to keep Volume 1 warmer
source(S)|   |  |
             +--+
```

**How do we figure out what affect adding the second volume will have on the temperature of the first, upper volume?**

**For context**, this question was actually raised initially from the topic of winter camping in cold areas. Someone had heard of advise to dig a hole straight down through the snow in the bottom of your igloo to give cold air a lower place to go that won't bother you, keeping the rest of the igloo slightly warmer. We are skeptical, but we are hoping to approach this logically instead of just dismissing the idea. We want to figure out how to estimate the effect that such a hole would really have.

So the heat source is human bodies resting on the floor of the upper volume, and the heat loss is due to various things including draft from door and ventilation holes and from loss through insulation (not very significant I don't think, as the snow actually insulates surprisingly well).

Comment: I think the title of this does not make it clear at a glance. If anyone can suggest a better title that makes the question clear, especially since I don't know the thermodynamics lingo, I'd appreciate it. Similar goes for the body too I suppose; if I've misused any terms or need to make similar adjustments, I'm open to that.

Comment: I've heard of the idea that the portal to the outside would be placed below the heated level and below the outside level.  There it would function as a "cold trap", so that heated air didn't flow out the exit and leave.  But that's because the exit is necessary to have in the first place.  Not that the hole is dug to give cold air somewhere to go.

Comment: @BowlOfRed Yes, I agree completely, and that was what I thought the person was talking about at first, but then I realized that they had heard of digging a separate hole to collect cold air at a lower elevation. I think that the benefit would not even be noticeable, quite negligible, but I don't want to dismiss it in case I'm wrong.

Comment: And I would just go test it, except that this would not be an easy thing to test.

Comment: Where do you presume the heat sink and source are placed in the room?

Comment: @Deep Does that matter? Seriously, I don't know if it matters. I wasn't even sure if it mattered that they existed at all. In my use case that I mentioned, I was thinking of the humans in the igloo as the heat source, and the heat sink being losses out the side because of imperfect insulation or from drafts coming in around the door or ventilation holes.

Comment: @Deep That said, do I need to specify in my ascii-text diagram that the heat source is in the middle of the bottom of the upper volume? And if the nature of the sink matters, how would you suggest I edit that in?

Comment: @Aaron I asked because the geometry of placement of heat sources/sinks determines the nature of convection, which is presumably the primary mechanism by which heat is transferred from source to sink. In the attached bottom volume air will be stably stratified (because it doesn't contain source/sink) and so will not participate in convection. The convection flow in the room will be modified somewhat due to presence of bottom volume, but I doubt there will be significant effect on heat transfer aspects.

Comment: I was not even thinking about the different types of heat transfer, but you're right, that could change things. Do you think there is enough information to answer? Also, can I take your comment to imply that you would assume the existence of the lower volume would only negligibly effect the temperature of the upper volume?